# Formula for bulk buying with value based on available stock

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm putting together a simulated economy for a game and need help putting together the formula for calculating the total cost of a bulk exchange, where the value of the items changes based on how many are available.
I have a formula for single-item exchange, which is

$v=\frac{a}{b}\times{c}$

Where

a = desired amount

b = amount available

c = value when a = b

Would I just use the average of the above value and the calculated value after the exchange? 
Like 
$v=\frac{(\frac{a}{b}\times{c})+(\frac{a}{b-n}\times{c})}{2}$

I apologize in advance if I've missed something, or asked an obvious question

Comment: No, that average is at best an estimate of the average cost per unit. if $b-n$ is high, it is pretty reasonable, but if $b - n$ is low, particularly when $<10$, it is a poor estimate. And again, it is an estimate of cost per unit. To estimate the total cost, you have to multiply by $n$. A better estimate of total cost would be $ac\,\ln\left(\frac{b}{b-n}\right)$ where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm. But the only way to get the actual cost is sum up $$\frac 1b + \frac 1{b-1} + \dots + \frac 1{b-n}$$then multiply the result by $ac$.